# How to print yanked data in replace mode?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, replace

I want to paste data from clipboard. But instead of insert the data, I want to overwrite (like using `R`).

Comment: Can we have an example?

Answer (score 3):

You can visual-select the text you want to overwrite and then paste from clipboard. For a single word, that would be `ve` to select until the end of the word to replace and `"+p` to insert the clipboard's contents over the selection.

Works especially well if the text to replace and the text to insert differ in lengths.

Comment: @Antonio I really appreciate your edit to my answer. However, I can't get it to work, at least not from clipboard (it's probably me). Therefore, I removed the sentence again. Hope to see an answer of your own explaining your idea.

Comment: I think the key is "the **last** visual operation".  If you do a visual selection but no operation on the selected text, it don't works. Indeed it works if you make a visual selection and then yank the text. I restore the part with gif to show how it works.

Comment: @Antonio this is getting a little bit surreal, me arguing with my own post. I think OP's first sentence is key: *"I want to paste data from clipboard."* i.e. not from a buffer. What you write is neat, it's great, it also doesn't actually answer the question IMHO. Hence my reservations. Please do write an answer of your own. Your edits earned you 4 rep while what you write (with that nice animated gif) is good for at least two upvotes or 20 rep.

Comment: You are right.  I did a mistake between register and clipboard.
And I understand, it' is funny to edit and re-edit your post, I thought there was a simpler way to reply to your comment.   

Thanks for your kind way to reply to me and to delete my OT additions. :-)

Comment: P.S. I spent one hour and half to figurate how to record the vim window with keys I pushed. 

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

1. `R` go to replace mode
2. <kbd>Ctrl r</kbd>`*` paste

Remark: if you have yank the clipboard from a visual selection you could also do:

1. `1v` replicate the visual selection shape from the original visual selection
2. `p` paste over

You could use that technique even if the clipboard has not been yanked using visual selection by "forcing" it:

1. `P` past before
2. `v` go to visual mode
3. `` `. `` got the start of the edition
4. `y` yank again
5. `v` leave visual mode
6. `l` go no next character
7. `1v` restore selection
8. `d` delete the part that you would like to override

Answer (score 1):

If your terminal supports bracketed paste, I would expect `R<paste>` to work fine, where `<paste>` is something like Ctrl/Cmd-V, or a middle click, or whatever your system’s paste command is.